# Word to refer "cabin window"

Tags: word-choice

Like the ones in a:

- cinema ticket selling point
- purge contention chamber (sci-fi)
- reception point of a public institution
- police control point

(where one can attend someone else, behind a security glass)

Comment: Can you give an example of how you really want to use the word.  I think in many cases you would use "glass"  "She banged on the glass of the ticket booth", or "window" would also work, especially when it separates inside from outside.... Also "purge contention chamber" makes no sense.

Comment: thx for answer, the intent is not use it for narrative, only to know the exact term in english; in a context where building something like facility installations and need to know the "technical" term, specialized jargon.

Comment: Here are some *windows* for sale, using that term qualified by the context:  https://tinyurl.com/d5tz3xz6    By *contention*, did you mean *containment*?

Comment: "Window" would seem to the term to use.  "ticket window, transition window" I don't think there is a more specific term, but I'm not an architect.  You may do better asking your fellow builder and architects.

Comment: probably yes, thx James K for feedback